# Efficiently dropping rows from a DataFrame if some row-values are identical with row-values in a second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':   [ 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3], 
                    'nr':   [91, 92, 93, 91, 92, 93, 91, 92, 93], 
                    'val_a':[22, 23, 24, 33, 34, 35, 44, 43, 42]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':   [ 1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  3,  5], 
                    'nr':   [91, 92, 91, 99, 92, 93, 92, 99], 
                    'val_a':[72, 27, 74, 83, 84, 85, 84, 83]})

def eliminate1 (): 
    for i1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
        for i2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
            if row1['id'] == row2['id'] and row1['nr'] == row2['nr']:
                df1.drop(i1, inplace=True)
    df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    print(df1)

eliminate1()
```

I want to drop all rows from df1, where 'id' AND 'nr' have equal values in any row of df2. eliminate1() works well, see result below, but is very slow in case of large data sets.

Here are df1 and df2:

```
   id  nr  val_a
0   1  91     22
1   1  92     23
2   1  93     24
3   2  91     33
4   2  92     34
5   2  93     35
6   3  91     44
7   3  92     43
8   3  93     42 

   id  nr  val_a
0   1  91     72
1   1  92     27
2   2  91     74
3   3  99     83
4   4  92     84
5   4  93     85
6   3  92     84
7   5  99     83
```

And here the result as it should look like:

```
   id  nr  val_a
0   1  93     24
1   2  92     34
2   2  93     35
3   3  91     44
4   3  93     42
```

Does anyone know how to write a faster code and/or use an already existing function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

You can `merge` with `indicator=True` and include only those rows marked `'left_only'`.

```
res = df1.merge(df2.drop('val_a', 1), how='left', on=['id', 'nr'], indicator=True)
res = res.loc[res['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop('_merge', 1)

print(res)

   id  nr  val_a
2   1  93     24
4   2  92     34
5   2  93     35
6   3  91     44
8   3  93     42
```

The solution is easily adaptable to any condition depending on `'left_only'`, `'right_only'` or `'both'`.

Answer (score 4):

Method 1 `isin` after zip the `merge` column into `tuple`

```
df1[~df1[['id','nr']].apply(tuple,1).isin(df2[['id','nr']].apply(tuple,1))]
Out[43]: 
   id  nr  val_a
2   1  93     24
4   2  92     34
5   2  93     35
6   3  91     44
8   3  93     42
```

Method 2 `numpy` broadcast

```
s1=df1[['id','nr']].values
s2=df2[['id','nr']].values
df1[~np.any(np.all(s1==s2[:,None],-1),0)]
Out[64]: 
   id  nr  val_a
2   1  93     24
4   2  92     34
5   2  93     35
6   3  91     44
8   3  93     42
```

My method timing

```
%timeit df1[~df1[['id','nr']].apply(tuple,1).isin(df2[['id','nr']].apply(tuple,1))]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.67 ms per loop
def m2():
    s1 = df1[['id', 'nr']].values
    s2 = df2[['id', 'nr']].values
    return df1[~np.any(np.all(s1 == s2[:, None], -1), 0)]
%timeit m2()
1000 loops, best of 3: 926 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Would an `inner join` solve your problem? Get the index of params that match the condition then filter it out. You'll just have to `reset_index()` afterwards if you wish to do so.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'inner', on = ['id','nr']).reset_index()
id_list = df3['id'].tolist()
df4 = df1[~df1['id'].isin(id_list)]
```